# Drop database owned by specific user in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have created database with bad symbols at the end of its name.
Now I want to drop it but I don't know how to type its name in the console.
Can I remove databases owned by this user? I tried to `DROP OWNED BY devuser` but it does not worked. I see just `DROP OWNED` in the console.

[image: command prompt]

Comment: So what error did you get from the `DROP` statement?

Comment: What happens if you use an UTF-8 enabled client, so that you can actually read that character?. Then you should be able to drop that database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try this from your shell:

```
-bash-4.1$ bad_dbname=$(psql -t -q -c "select datname from pg_database where datname like 'bsw_ui%' limit 1")
-bash-4.1$ echo "the next command will drop ${bad_dbname}"
-bash-4.1$ psql -c "drop database ${bad_dbname}"
```

I verified this works using bash4.1 on centos6.3 with posgresql8.4 for a database using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602912/how-do-you-echo-a-4-digit-unicode-character-in-bash) unicode character. YMMV

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I would just like to offer a suggestion that has worked for me before.  You can copy the symbol to clipboard and then past into the commands you need to use such as DROP TABLE

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem. The only solution I can think of involves a lot of coding.

My suggestion would be to SELECT the name of the database out of [pg_database](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/catalog-pg-database.html) and then craft a statement in [PL/PGSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql.html) inside a [function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createfunction.html) and then use [dynamic sql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/plpgsql-statements.html) to EXECUTE the statement. For this to work, you need to be in another database and also create/run the function in another database.